# How to access spring app inside docker container from browser using static Ip

Tags: spring, docker

I made docker image from Spring Boot Jar file using command below command

```
1) docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-spring-boot .
```

Then to run container

```
docker run -p 8087:8080 docker-spring-boot
```

When I tried to connect to my application from browser it cannot connect to it. I use **Ubuntu-16.04**. Server use internet with **95.158.123.124** static Ip. When I see Ip address of my docker container using below command. It is showing me **172.17.0.2**

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_name_or_id
```

Here My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD jarfolder/docker-spring-boot.jar docker-spring-boot.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/docker-spring-boot.jar"]
```

In my Ubuntu server Apache server is running. Maybe I need to set some configuration in server or docker.
I am trying to connect to may app using **http://95.158.123.124:8087/rest/docker/hello** but cannot connect. Please Help me

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is almost useless; for example, you can't connect to it from other hosts.  You should be able to use the host IP address and the first port number from the `docker run -p` option, so `http://...:8087/...`.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what should i do now?

Comment: Is the application starting up?  Does it print out any log messages?  Does it say something like "listening on localhost:8080" or "listening on 0.0.0.0:8080"?  When you say "cannot connect", where are you calling from, with what tool, and what behavior do you actually see?

Comment: Yes it is running. when i run command docker ps -a. It is showing running process. in logs it is showing. Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 with context.

Comment: I am calling app from Firefox browser

Comment: Firefox cannot establish connection to the server.  This kind of page is opened when i try

Comment: when i run command docker ps -a. in ports section:   8087/tcp,  0.0.0.0:8087->8080/tcp     is written

Comment: What you get, when you open in firefox ```http://localhost:8087/rest/docker/hello``` ?